# Why does the Form Submit insert '?' at the end of the URL? How to prevent it?

Tags: html, forms

Why does the Form Submit insert '?' at the end of the URL? And How to prevent it?

Like this:

```
<form action="http://www.the-sample-website.com" target="_blank">
  <button type="submit">Button Submit</button>
</form>
```

Send to: `http://www.the-sample-website.com/?`

Running Sample:
https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=GFUVYSHBKS7K

Comment: Probably because you don't specify a page, just a server.  So the server must decide what page to load for you.    `http://www.the-sample-website.com/my-page.php` or  just  `my-page.php` would not add `?` unless there is some redirect in place.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/submit

Comment: @DaveS your sample URL also adds the '?'. You can try it at the running sample url

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you are not specifying the `method` of your form, which is why you are experiencing a `GET` method.

The default `method` for a `<form>` element is `GET`, which is one or more variables that are parsed in the `URL`.

That's why you sometimes see examples like this in a URL:

`www.example-site.com?id=1`

Or

`www.example-site.com?id=1&name=bob`

In this example, the `GET` variables are `id` and `name`. Depending on your server side language, you can retrieve these variables.

Example using PHP:

```
<?php
$myVar = $_GET['id'];
// $myVar2 = $_GET['name'];
?>
```

This will store the `GET` variable parsed in the `URL` example I gave earlier.

To prevent the form from using a `GET` `method`, define your `method` to be a `POST` in your `<form>` tag.

Example:

```
<form action="http://www.the-sample-website.com" method="post">
    <!-- Your form stuff -->
</form>
```

**EDIT:**

> *Nice @Martin. But do I have to set method "post" even if I want to redirect without form-data?*
>
> @Victor Soares

**Answer:** If all you want to do is redirect without sending any data, then you don't need a `<form>` at all. You can simply use an `<a>` tag, or if you want to keep your button logic, make a JavaScript function that does the redirect for you.

**Example:**

```js
function redirector(){
  alert('this function redirects to Google');
 var url = "https://www.google.com/"
 window.location.href = url;
}

const redirectButton = document.querySelector('#redirectButton');

redirectButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
 redirector();
});
```

```html
<button id="redirectButton">I take you to Google!</button>
```

Comment: Nice @Martin. But do I have to set method "post" even if I want to redirect without form-data?